# make a list into a collection in TCL

Tags: collections, tcl, synopsys-vcs

I want to create a collection from a list.
`friends1` is a list of names.

I am trying to do:

```
    set friends2 ""          
    foreach frnd $friends1 {
        append_to_collection friends2 $frnd
    }
```

> Error: At least one collection required for argument 'object_spec'
>           to append_to_collection when the 'collection' argument is empty (SEL-014)

Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: What code defines `append_to_collection`? It's not standard Tcl (as defined in http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/)

Comment: I'm using ic compiler and it is a built in command: append_to_collection
              Adds objects to a collection and modifies a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Synopsys collections can only be made from Synopsys objects, like nets, pins, etc.  Friend is not a Synopsys object...but assuming instead you have a list of names of Synopsys objects, you can use the respective 'get' function to turn the list into a collection.

```
set col_of_nets [get_nets $nets]
set col_of_pins [get_pins $pins]
...
```

To go backwards (collection to list of names), use get_object_name.

```
set names_of_nets [get_object_name $col_of_nets]
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Its old question. But still not answered.

You need to create a collection first to append to it.

Here is a short video about how to do it...

https://www.usessionbuddy.com/user/vlsicoder/termtosvg_v6ai8tfv.svg/